# Showing that $f:M\mapsto M$ has a unique fixed point if $M$ is compact and $d(f(a),f(b))<d(a,b)~\forall a,b\in M$

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness, fixed-point-theorems

I'm not sure if this is a good approach (I know there is a different proof that involves a function $a\mapsto d(a,f(a))$ whose minimum is the unique fixed point):

For any $a\ne b\in M$ we have that $d(f(a),f(b))<d(a,b)$ equivalently there exists $k(a,b)\in[0,1)$ such that $d(f(a),f(b))\le kd(a,b)$

Let's impose that $k:M\times M\mapsto[0,1)$ is is the smallest $k\in[0,1)$ such that $d(f(a),f(b))\le k d(a,b)$ for a given $(a,b)\in M\times M$

> I think $k$ is continuous because $f$ is continuous (by choosing $\delta = \varepsilon$), but I don't know how to prove that.

Once we have that $k$ is continuous, since $M\times M$ is compact it has a maximum, $k^*\in[0,1)$ and now we have all we need to apply Banach's fixed point theorem to $f:M\mapsto M$ which is a $k^*$-contraction and because $M$ is complete as a compact space.

Comment: No, this is not a good approach. Instead, look for a point $x\in M$ which minimizes $d(x, f(x))$.

Comment: You are essentially arguing that $(a,b)\mapsto \frac{d(f(a),f(b))}{d(a,b)}$ is continuous. But there's a problem on the diagonal $a=b$.

Comment: @MoisheCohen yes that's what I wrote in the parenthesis (first line), I'm aware of that proof

Comment: Why do you want to apply Banach's FPT?. The compactness is a much stronger condition. Compactness implies that the sequence $a, f(a), f(f(a)), ... $ must have a converging subsequence (where the limit is the FP), and by $d(f(a),f(b)) <d(a,b)$ the sequence itself must converge to the FP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(x) = \sin x$ for $0\le x\le 1$. Then by mean value theorem, there exists $c\in (x,y)$ such that
$$
|f(x)-f(y)| = \cos c\cdot |x-y|<|x-y|
$$ for all $x\ne y$. This shows $f$ satisfies the condition of the problem. However, $$k(x,y) =\frac{|\sin x-\sin y|}{|x-y|}, \quad x\ne y$$ can be arbitrarily close to $1$ near $(0,0)$ as we can see from MVT and $\lim\limits_{c\to 0}\cos c= 1$. Hence there is no $k^*<1$ such that $k(x,y)\le k^*$. Unfortunately, Banach's fixed point theorem cannot be applied in this case, thus it cannot be a general approach to the problem.